# Busquedad por valor numerico sql net mvc2

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc

debo filtrar los datos por los datos de la tabla domicilio, me funciona bien con string pero con int no.

```
public ActionResult Buscar(string palabra)
        {
            IEnumerable<domicilio> domicilios;

            using (var bd = new serviexpressEntities2())
            {
                domicilios = bd.domicilio;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(palabra))
                {
                    domicilios = domicilios.Where(l => l.cedula.Contains(palabra) || l.documento.Contains(palabra) || l.direccion1.Contains(palabra) || l.direccion2.Contains(palabra) || l.modo_pago.Contains(palabra));

                }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(palabra))
                {
                    int pr = Convert.ToInt32("palabra");
                    return View(domicilios.Where(x => x.precio == pr));
                }


                domicilios = domicilios.ToList();
            }

            return View(domicilios);
        }
```

Cuando hago la busquedad me señala error en la linea:

```
 int pr = Convert.ToInt32("palabra");
```

el error es: a
segurese de que sus argumentosde metodo tiene el formato correcto al darle click aparece:

> {"La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto."}

Answer (score 0):

No se exactamente lo que intentas pero el string "palabra" nunca sera un intero:

```
// imposible, como puede, por ejemplo, la letra p ser convertido a intero? o la letra a?
int pr = Convert.ToInt32("palabra");
```

Quizas lo que quieres es convertir *el valor de la variable* `palabra` a entero, no el String "palabra".

Utiliza el metodo `int.TryParse()` donde valida si un `string` no es valido para ser convertido a entero entonces retorna `false`, de lo contrario `true`:

```
public ActionResult Buscar(string palabra)
{
    IEnumerable<domicilio> domicilios;

    using (var bd = new serviexpressEntities2())
    {
        domicilios = bd.domicilio;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(palabra))
        {
            domicilios = domicilios.Where(l => l.cedula.Contains(palabra) || l.documento.Contains(palabra) || l.direccion1.Contains(palabra) || l.direccion2.Contains(palabra) || l.modo_pago.Contains(palabra));

        }

        int pr = 0;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(palabra) && int.TryPase(palabra, out pr) == true)
        {
            return View(domicilios.Where(x => x.precio == pr));
        }


        domicilios = domicilios.ToList();
    }

    return View(domicilios);
}
```

Comment: me sale el error Asegurese de que no ha liberado ningun recurso antes de utilizarlo. en la vista

Comment: Advertencia 1 Validación (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): el elemento 'p' no se puede anidar dentro del elemento 'p'. C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\serviexpress\serviexpress\Views\Domicilio\Buscar.aspx 14 18 serviexpress

Comment: A ver, cual de los 2 es el error que te muestra primero el que dice que libere el recurso?

Comment: si es el primero apuntando a una linea que aparece asi:<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

Comment: Intenta cambiando  `return View(domicilios.Where(x => x.precio == pr));` por  `return View(domicilios.Where(x => x.precio == pr).ToList());`. Fijate que se le agrega un `.ToList()` despues del `Where`

Comment: listo, no sale error: pero cuando busco el precio no me devuelve ningun resultado?

Comment: Bueno, en ese caso tendrias que comprobar que estes haciendo la consulta correcta. No crees?